# How would you create a test for a Constructor?

Tags: java, testing

I'm creating tests for an already complied program, and I'm having trouble getting 100% coverage.

The constructor for a class is:

```
public Contact(String name, String email){
     if (name == null){
           throw new IllegalAgrugmentException("name must not be null");
     }
}
```

The test I created reads:

```
public void testForContactConstructor(){
        Contact testContact = new Contact(null, null);
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            testContact.getName();
        });
    }
```

The test doesn't get covered in eclispe. How would I fix this?

Comment: You need to make 2 different test cases, one with name = null and other with name = "someValidName"

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion seems like it should be

```java
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
  contact = new Contact(null, null);
});
```

Otherwise it will throw before getting to your assert :(

Other than that i need a little more information, what test framework are you using? There could be annotations missing

All in all you could do something like this (depending on how complex a constructor) :

```java
public void TestContactConstructorFail(){
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () ->
      new Contact(null, null));
}

public void TestContactConstructorSuccess(){
    Contact c = new Contact(name,email);
    assertNotNull(c); //leave the rest for get/set test
}
```

(add any framework specific annotations as well, e.g. `@Test` for Junit)

IF you have complex validation or other things in your constructor, i would recommend delegating these to private(ish) methods and testing these separately.

Comment: I'm using java on the program eclipse. With your edit I got the assertThrows to be covered but not the Contact testContact = new Contact(null, null) to be covered.

Comment: That must be because the lambda throws before completion. Generally you should only worry about how much of your actual code (non-test code) is covered. So if we have a line of test code that doesnt register as having run there might be redundancy, but other than that it is not much of a concern. You can add a *positive test* of your constructor as well if you want to cover field initialization and such (one where you use actual values instead of nulls). :)